# Raspberry Pi Pico not executing main.py upon 5V

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, micropython, raspberry-pi-pico, circuit

I have a Raspberry Pi Pico W with code on it that lights up the onboard LED once it has successfully connected to WiFi, otherwise the onboard LED will blink. Most times upon start up however, (I have a 9V battery connected to a 5V breadboard power supply) the LED does not turn on, leading me to believe the Pico is not executing the main.py script that the code is named as.

Is there something I'm missing in order to execute code upon activation on a Pico W? Thank you!

I have verified that the code works when connected to my laptop via USB and ran through Thonny.

Comment: Why dont you attach a serial console to it and see what it does instead of assuming things? That would be the first thing while debugging.

Comment: By serial console do you mean an IDE console? I've verified the code works on Thonny & the Pico if that's what you mean. It successfully prints the "Connecting" message and states the LED is turned on, followed by "Successfully connected"

Comment: If your code works as expected in IDE, but does not work once connected to breadboard- your power supply is to weak. WIFI requires substantial amount of power when connecting, and your power supply is to weak.